# Issue with regex pattern/matcher

Tags: java, regex

```
String s2 = "K000";
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("/^.*([A-Z])/");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(s2);

if (m2.find()) {    
    int pos2 = m2.end();
    a2 = s2.substring(0,pos2);
    n2 = s2.substring(pos2);
}
```

I would expect a2 to be assigned the value "K" and n2 to be assigned the value "000", but m2.find() never evaluates to true so the conditional statements are never processed.  I double checked my regex pattern on an online regex tester and for this string and this pattern it returns K as a match.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Ultimately, what I need to happen is to be able to assign from the beginning s2 all the way to the last capitol alpha found to a2 and any lowercase, numerics, special characters that occur after the last capitol alpha to n2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the `/`.

Comment: Omit the javascript regex delimiters you're using, i.e. `Pattern.compile("^.*([A-Z])");`

Comment: Java, javascript, same thing no? ;-P  Thanks so much for picking out what I was doing wrong.  I've been banging my head on it for what seems like hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `/` from regex it will work.

So your final regex will be `^.*([A-Z])` and `Pattern` object will be created as follows:

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^.*([A-Z])");
```

This will give you the desired result.

Comment: Indeed it does!

Comment: @Chad If you face issue with regex you can try out http://regexr.com/. It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` are Javascript regex delimiters, you don't use them in Java. You probably used a Javascript regex tester.

[See this example:](http://ideone.com/cfNK5l)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s2 = "K000";
    String a2 = "";
    String n2 = "";

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^.*([A-Z])");
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(s2);
    if (m2.find()) {
        int pos2 = m2.end();
        a2 = s2.substring(0, pos2);
        n2 = s2.substring(pos2);
    }

    System.out.println(a2); // K
    System.out.println(n2); // 000
}
```

Note that you could also use another pattern, which seems a bit more straightforward (and lets the matcher do the work for you).

[See this example:](http://ideone.com/FGSBok)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s2 = "K000";
    String a2 = "";
    String n2 = "";

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)(.+)");
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(s2);
    if (m2.matches()) {
        a2 = m2.group(1);
        n2 = m2.group(2);
    }

    System.out.println(a2); // K
    System.out.println(n2); // 000
}
```

(replace `+` by `*` if you don't want to require at least one character)